# Spring interceptor not work

Tags: spring-mvc, configuration, interceptor

I coded an interceptor as follows:

```
package org.mybatis.jpetstore.interceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.mybatis.jpetstore.annotation.CsrfTokenCheck;
import org.mybatis.jpetstore.tool.CsrfTokenTool;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class CsrfTokenAnnotationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object ojbect) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("======================");
        //if(ojbect instanceof HandlerMethod){
            CsrfTokenCheck csrfTokenCheck = ((HandlerMethod) ojbect).getMethodAnnotation(CsrfTokenCheck.class);

            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++");
            if(csrfTokenCheck != null && !new CsrfTokenTool().verify((HttpServletRequest) request)){
                response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
                return false;
            }
        //}

        return true;
    }
}
```

but it seems not work at all.(the codes depend on spring3.2)

annotation in controller:

```
@CsrfTokenCheck
    public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("category/category");

        return mav;
    }
```

interface:

```
package org.mybatis.jpetstore.annotation;

public @interface CsrfTokenCheck{
}
```

I also configued something as follows in my spring-config.xml:

```
<bean id="requestMappingHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">   
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>  
            <ref bean="csrfTokenAnnotationInterceptor" />  
        </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>

<bean id="csrfTokenAnnotationInterceptor" class="org.mybatis.jpetstore.interceptor.CsrfTokenAnnotationInterceptor" />
```

Comment: the first line in xml is:<bean id="requestMappingHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"> , i dont know what's wrong with this side... If I input "<bean id="requestMappingHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">", it will be disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Start by fixing your annotation. It should contain at least a `@Retention` meta-annotation and make it available at runtime, currently it isn't and as such will also fail.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CsrfTokenCheck{}
```

Next to that make sure you don't have an `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your configuration as that will render your explicitly configured `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` useless. If you are using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` you should use the `<mvc:interceptors />` tag to register interceptors.

Answer (score 1):

Check these files:

- `resources/spring/spring.xml`

```xml
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
         ...
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml"/>
    </bean>
```

- `resources/mybatis/mybatis-config.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    ...
    <plugins>
        <!-- Interceptor configuration -->
        <plugin interceptor="com.w.pay.api.test.mvn.res.db.MybatisLogPrinter" />
    </plugins>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello @kyakya, is there another way to configure plugin settings in just one integrated context xml file, not separated in other files such as the mybatis-config.xml file you just mentioned? But the solution you provide works, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please search for interceptors in all XML files in your workspace.

I solved this by realizing that the servlet-context file already exists where the annotation driven and other interceptors are defined. After placing my interceptor definition in that file it worked like a charm.

I spent quite 1.5 day scratching my head, it turns out that spring does not like multiple locations for interceptors.